# how to create a list from a reversed array in php

Tags: php, logic, jquery-ui-sortable

I use `jQuery nestedSortable Plugin`, which returns a list of items whenever they change their order. So from a list like following:

```
Item 371
Item 372
    Item 373
    Item 374
Item 375
```

I receive the following array:

```
'0' ...
    'id' => "371"
    'parent_id' ...
    'depth' => "0"
    'has_child' => "0"
'1' ...
    'id' => "373"
    'parent_id' => "372"
    'depth' => "1"
    'has_child' => "0"
'2' ...
    'id' => "374"
    'parent_id' => "372"
    'depth' => "1"
    'has_child' => "0"
'3' ...
    'id' => "372"
    'parent_id' ...
    'depth' => "0"
    'has_child' => "1"
'4' ...
    'id' => "375"
    'parent_id' ...
    'depth' => "0"
    'has_child' => "0"
```

What I am doing now is I am storing the priority (which is `array no`) to each and every item.

Problem is that by the provided array, child items get higher priority (in the example above `1` and `2`) compared to their parent item (in the example above `3`).

Now this makes it impossible to recreate a list whenever the view is reloaded as child item would be echoed before the parent.

Is there any other way to recreate the list out of this array?

**EDIT**

Elements cannot have granchilds, and `depth` can only be `0` or `1`.

Comment: Can elements have grand-children (and deeper descendants)?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that. No, depth is maximum at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach (where $list is Your given array):

```
$queue=array();
foreach($list as $v){
    if($v['parent_id']==0){
        echo 'Item '.$v['id'];
        foreach($queue as $child){
            echo ': Item '.$child['id'];
        }
        $queue=array();
    }
    else {
        $queue[]=$v;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I will go with your solution as there are not too many records to iterate over.